# Use different structs as a value in map golang

Tags: go

Is there any way to create a map into several structs, and then use It?

I have several different structs that implement the same interface and matching input types for each struct.

I want to read data from the different inputs into the structs - without knowing the input type at the compilation time.

```
type myInput struct {
    InputType  string
    data       []bytes
}

// Will get as an input after compeleation
inputs := []myInput{
    myInput{InputType: "a", data: []bytes{0x01, 0x02, 0x03}},
    myInput{InputType: "b", data: []bytes{0x01, 0x02}},
}

type StructA struct {
   A uint16
   B uint32
}

func (a StructA) name () {
    fmt.Printf("name is: %d %d", a.A, a.B)
}

type StructB struct {
   C uint32
}

func (b StructB) name () {
    fmt.Printf("name is: %d", b.C)
}

AorB map[string]<???> {
    "a": StructA,
    "b": StructB,
}
```

At this point, I don't know what to do. I need to take the correct struct by the input type and initialize the struct using `binary.Read`.

```
for _, myInput := range (inputs) {
    // ???? :(
    myStruct := AtoB[myInput.InputType]{}
    reader :=bytes.NewReader(input1)
    err := binary.Read(reader, binary.BigEndian, &myStruct)
    fmt.Printf(myStruct.name())
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use the empty interface. `map[string]interface{}{ ... }`.

Comment: No. Redesign.  Seems the map itself is not a real map but some device for dynamic dispatch here.

Comment: @Volker Can you explain more, please?
I also tried to do `map[string]types.Type` buy it didn't work as well.

Comment: I'm not talking about the codomain of the map but the map itself. You seem to use a map as a way to "switch" between memory layouts (based on a string) and probably this switching device should be redesigned. E.g. you did not show what you do to `myStruct` after populating it.

Comment: @Volker Thanks. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Define a interface

```
type Bin interface {
    name() string
    set([]byte) // maybe returning error
}
```

You'll be handling `Bin`s only.

```
type StructA struct { /* your code so far */ }
type StructB struct { /* your code so far */ }

func (a *StructA) set(b []byte) {
    a.A = b[0]<<8 + b[1] // get that right, too lazy to code this for you
    a.B = b[2]<<24 + b[3]<<16 + ...  
}
// same for StructB
```

So your StructA/B are Bins now.

```
func makeBin(in myInput) Bin {
     var bin Bin
     if in.InputType == "a" {
         bin = &StructA{}
     } else {
         bin = &StructB{}
     }
     bin.set(in.data) // error handling?
     return bin
}
```

If you have more than two types: Use a switch instead if an `if` or make a tiny type registry (reflect).

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses.
Unfortunately, this is not what I was looking for :(
My goal is to replace the "ugly" huge switch case - because I have more than just 2 types.

Comment: @user305229 Good luck than. Because that's not how Go works.

Answer (score 1):

First you define an `interface` for the commonly used `func` `name`:

```
type Namer interface {
    name()
}
```

Then you can create a map to that interface and insert structs:

```
AorB := map[string] Namer {
    "a": StructA{
        A: 42,
        B: 28,
    },
    "b": StructB{
        C: 12,
    },
}
```

Now you can access all entries:

```
for _, n := range AorB {
    n.name()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But than the problem will be here:
    AorB := map[string] Namer {
        "a": StructA{},
        "b": StructB{},
    }
As I want to initilize the structs with data

Comment: Yes, of course you can initialize them with data. I'll extend my answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can use interface for the same

```
AorB := map[string]interface{}{
    "a": StructA{},
    "b": StructB{},
}
```

When you retrieve value back you can assert into A for type A and B for type B

Comment: This does not work. `type StructA is not an expression`

Comment: You are passing a type. When you pass a struct (`StructA{}`) it works. But if you want to call a func of an element you still have to type check.

Comment: Yes its a typo error. It should be structA{}, structB{}